# Using @TestFor in unit test for bean that uses constructor arguments throws an error (Grails 2.0.0RC1)

Tags: grails

I'm trying to create a unit test for a service class that uses a constructor argument. I have already configured an entry in the grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy to allow Spring to create the bean using the constructor argument.

Running an integration test for the service class works without problem, however, running a unit test that uses @TestFor, the following exception shows up:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleService': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [ph.jojopad.SampleService]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ph.jojopad.SampleService.<init>()
    at grails.test.mixin.services.ServiceUnitTestMixin.mockService(ServiceUnitTestMixin.groovy:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [ph.jojopad.SampleService]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ph.jojopad.SampleService.<init>()
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ph.jojopad.SampleService.<init>()
```

It seems that @TestFor only expects a bean that uses the default constructor. Looking at the documentation of Grails I can't find any references on how to use @TestFor for beans with constructor arguments. I was expecting that with the correct bean configuration at grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy would do the trick.

Comment: The Grails developers confirmed that this feature is not yet available: (http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8356)

Comment: The Grails developers confirmed that this feature is not yet available: